# Word that describes something that performs as advertised or expected

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for a specific word, but I can't remember what it was. It begins with "a" I believe, and its definition is something along the lines of "successful in its endeavor, successful in its purpose". It's an adjective, and you would use it to describe something that was or would be successful in it's goal. For example, you could describe a product that did as it advertised using this adjective. I believe it's 3 or 4 syllables but I might be wrong.

EDIT: I was wrong. It began with "e". efficacious was the word I was looking for.

Comment: The one that comes to mind is "accessory", but that doesn't quite match that product bit.

Comment: Succeeded in his endeavor, **achieved** his purpose; **accomplished** his mission; **attained** his goal; **actualized** his dreams.

Comment: @Jeremy As a user of other SE sites, you will know that you can answer your own question (and even accept your own answer after a while). This marks the question in the list as answered.

Comment: *Not a rip-off?*

Answer (score 1):

**efficacious**: (typically of something inanimate or abstract) successful in producing a desired or intended result; effective.

That's what I was looking for.

Comment: You may also use "compliant" to describe a product meeting expected goals. (for an adjective beginning with a "a": perhaps *adequate*)